# Node.js Express App with OpenAI API - "URL is not defined" error only on the server

Tags: openai-api

I'm developing a Node.js Express application that uses the OpenAI API for sentiment analysis. The app works perfectly when run locally, but when I deploy it to my server, I encounter an error stating URL is not defined. The strange thing is that I don't directly use a URL object anywhere in my code.

Here's a simplified version of my server code:

```
require('dotenv').config()
const express = require('express');
const { Configuration, OpenAIApi } = require("openai");
const cors = require('cors');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const https = require('https');
const http = require('http');

// (omitting some setup code for brevity)

const app = express();

app.post('/analyze_sentiment', async (req, res) => {
    const expression = req.body.expression;
    let sentimentScore, flowerResponse;

    console.log("client sent" + req.body.expression)
    console.log("OPENAI apiKey:"+ process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY);
    try {
        // Get sentiment score
        let gptResponse = await openai.createCompletion({
            model: 'text-davinci-003',
            prompt: `This prompt is made for my webapp...`,
            temperature: 0.3,
            max_tokens: 60
        });
                console.log(sentimentScore);  THIS NEVER GOT PRINTED!

        sentimentScore = gptResponse.data.choices[0].text.trim();

        // (omitting some code for brevity)

        res.json({ sentimentScore: sentimentScore, flowerResponse: flowerResponse });
    } catch (error) {
        if (error.response) {
            console.log(error.response.status);
            console.log(error.response.data);
        } else {
            console.log(error.message);
        }
        // Respond with an error message
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'An error occurred while processing your request.' });


      }
    });

// (omitting some code for brevity)
```

The error appears when I make a POST request to the /analyze_sentiment endpoint (regardless of reaching the server through DNS or not). It is worth noting everything uses trusted HTTPS certs. When I run the application locally, everything works fine. However, when I deploy it to the server, I get a URL is not defined error.

I've checked the OpenAI Node.js library documentation and there is no mention of needing to define a URL object. I also don't use a URL object anywhere in my application code. I'm running the same Node.js version locally and on the server.

Any help in understanding why this error is occurring and how to fix it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Using Node + Express. Everything works perfect on my machine, but it doesn't work on the server. I get the same error: "URL is not defined". I self host and the whole Node App works fine, just the OpenAI package returns this error on the server. Praying for some help!